# Failing dll injection

Tags: c++, windows, dll, code-injection

I'm in the process of making a security program for my network. One of it's instances is to check and monitor what api's and libraries are called. The dll to do that and the program that go along with it are already finished. But there is a problem that I cant seem to fix.

When trying to inject my dll into system processes (such as explorer.exe, my main test system process) with `NtCreateThreadEx` I get the return value: C0000022, it means something along the lines of: Status_Access_Denied (it returns in NTSTATUS, but DWORD will do)

I have no idea what to do, I'm running as Administrator, I raised my privileges, and used the proper functions, still I get c0000022

Here's the code I'm using to inject

```
#include "main.h"

typedef DWORD NTSTATUS;

struct NtCreateThreadExBuffer{
    ULONG Size;
    ULONG Unknown1;
    ULONG Unknown2;
    PULONG Unknown3;
    ULONG Unknown4;
    ULONG Unknown5;
    ULONG Unknown6;
    PULONG Unknown7;
    ULONG Unknown8;
};


typedef NTSTATUS (WINAPI *LPFUN_NtCreateThreadEx)
(
 OUT PHANDLE hThread,
 IN ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess,
 IN LPVOID ObjectAttributes,
 IN HANDLE ProcessHandle,
 IN LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress,
 IN LPVOID lpParameter,
 IN BOOL CreateSuspended,
 IN ULONG StackZeroBits,
 IN ULONG SizeOfStackCommit,
 IN ULONG SizeOfStackReserve,
 OUT LPVOID lpBytesBuffer
);

using namespace std;

//#define CREATE_THREAD_ACCESS (PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ)
#define CREATE_THREAD_ACCESS ( PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS )

BOOL LoadDll(char *procName, char *dllName);
BOOL InjectDLL(DWORD dwProcessID, char *dllName);

BOOL LoadDll(char *dllName, DWORD dwProcID){

    printf("Process Id to Inject: %d",dwProcID);

    if(!dwProcID){
        printf("No vailid PID\n");
        return false;
    }

    FILE* FileCheck = fopen(dllName, "r");

    if(FileCheck==NULL){
        printf("\nUnable to inject %s", dllName);
        return false;
    }

    fclose(FileCheck);


    if(!InjectDLL(dwProcID, dllName)){

        printf("injection failed\n");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}

BOOL InjectDLL(DWORD dwProcessID, char *dllName){

    HANDLE hProc;
    HANDLE hToken;
    char buf[50]={0};
    LPVOID RemoteString, LoadLibAddy;

    if(!dwProcessID)return false;


    HANDLE hCurrentProc = GetCurrentProcess();

    if (!OpenProcessToken(hCurrentProc,TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES,&hToken)){

        printf("OpenProcessToken Error:%d\n", GetLastError());


    } else {

        if (!RaisePrivleges(hToken, (char*)SE_DEBUG_NAME)){

            printf("SetPrivleges SE_DEBUG_NAME Error:%d\n", GetLastError());

        }

    }


    if (hToken)CloseHandle(hToken);

    hProc = OpenProcess(CREATE_THREAD_ACCESS, FALSE, dwProcessID);

    printf("\nHandle to process: %x\n", hProc);

    if(!hProc){

        printf("OpenProcess() failed: %d", GetLastError());
        return false;

    }

    LoadLibAddy = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");


    if(!LoadLibAddy){

        printf("GetProcAddress() failed: %d", GetLastError());
        return false;

    }

    RemoteString = (LPVOID)VirtualAllocEx(hProc, NULL, strlen(dllName), MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

    if(RemoteString == NULL){

        printf("VirtualAllocEx() failed: %d", GetLastError());
        return false;

    }


    printf("\nRemote address: %x\n", RemoteString);

    if(WriteProcessMemory(hProc, (LPVOID)RemoteString, dllName, strlen(dllName), NULL) == NULL){

        printf("WriteProcessMemory() failed: %d", GetLastError());
        return false;

    }

/*
if(!CreateRemoteThread(hProc, NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibAddy, (LPVOID)RemoteString, NULL, NULL)){

  printf("CreateRemoteThread() failed: %d", GetLastError());
     return false;

}
*/

    HMODULE modNtDll = GetModuleHandle("ntdll.dll");


    if( !modNtDll )
    {
        printf("n failed to get module handle for ntdll.dll, Error=0x%.8x", GetLastError());
        return 0;
    }

    LPFUN_NtCreateThreadEx funNtCreateThreadEx =
                                                (LPFUN_NtCreateThreadEx) GetProcAddress(modNtDll, "NtCreateThreadEx");


    if( !funNtCreateThreadEx )
    {
        printf("n failed to get function (NTCreateThreadEx) address from ntdll.dll, Error=0x%.8x\nTrying CreateRemoteThread api\n", GetLastError());

        if(!CreateRemoteThread(hProc, NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibAddy, (LPVOID)RemoteString, NULL, NULL)){

            printf("CreateRemoteThread() failed: %d", GetLastError());
            return false;

        } else {
            printf("CreateRemoteThread success!\n");
            return true;
        }


        return 0;
    }


    NtCreateThreadExBuffer ntbuffer;

    memset (&ntbuffer,0,sizeof(NtCreateThreadExBuffer));
    DWORD temp1 = 0;
    DWORD temp2 = 0;
    HANDLE pRemoteThread = NULL;

    ntbuffer.Size = sizeof(NtCreateThreadExBuffer);
    ntbuffer.Unknown1 = 0x10003;
    ntbuffer.Unknown2 = 0x8;
    ntbuffer.Unknown3 = &temp2;
    ntbuffer.Unknown4 = 0;
    ntbuffer.Unknown5 = 0x10004;
    ntbuffer.Unknown6 = 4;
    ntbuffer.Unknown7 = &temp1;
    ntbuffer.Unknown8 = 0;

    NTSTATUS status = funNtCreateThreadEx(
                                          &pRemoteThread,
                                          0x1FFFFF,
                                          NULL,
                                          hProc,
                                          (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) LoadLibAddy,
                                          (LPVOID)RemoteString,
                                          FALSE, //start instantly
                                          NULL,
                                          NULL,
                                          NULL,
                                          &ntbuffer
                                         );

    printf("NTCreateThreadEx return: %x\n", status);

    // Resume the thread execution

    WaitForSingleObject(pRemoteThread, INFINITE);


    //Check the return code from remote thread function
    DWORD dwExitCode;
    if( GetExitCodeThread(pRemoteThread, (DWORD*) &dwExitCode) )
    {
        printf("\n Remote thread returned with status = %d\n", dwExitCode);
    }


    CloseHandle(pRemoteThread); 


    CloseHandle(hProc);
    return true;

}


BOOL RaisePrivleges( HANDLE hToken, char *pPriv ){

    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tkp;
    tkp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    tkp.Privileges[0].Luid.HighPart = 0;
    tkp.Privileges[0].Luid.LowPart = 0;

    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, pPriv, &tkp.Privileges[0].Luid)){

        printf("LookupPrivilegeValue Error:%d\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;

    }

    int iRet = AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tkp, 0x10, (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL, 0);

    if (iRet == NULL){

        printf( "AdjustTokenPrivileges Error:%d\n", GetLastError());
        return TRUE;

    } else {

        iRet = GetLastError();

        switch (iRet){

            case ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED:
                printf("AdjustTokenPrivileges ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED\n" );
                return FALSE;

            case ERROR_SUCCESS:
                return TRUE;

            default:
                printf("AdjustTokenPrivileges Unknow Error:%d\n", iRet);
                return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to edit your question to add your code directly into the question but it is **way too long** ! Are you really expecting someone to review your entire code ?!

Comment: No I'm not, in fact that code works fine, no errors and no problems right until I try injecting code into system processes. In other applications it works fine.

Comment: The problem is this question will be here still (and searchable by google) after that pastbin is long gone.

Comment: @Unknown: Code samples on pastbin don't last forever. When the code sample will be gone in a few days/months/years, this question will remain but will contain a dead-link.

Comment: I can add them to my post now, the problem was that I couldn't use the toolbar when I first posted this question.

Answer (score 3):

1) If you're running on VISTA or later then you're possibly trying to inject into a 'protected process' from a 'non protected process'. See [Process Security and Access Rights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684880%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in MSDN. Non protected processes can't create threads in protected processes; though I must admit I'd expect the call to open process to fail when you request the inappropriate access rights rather than the subsequent create thread call to fail.

2) Why are you using `NtCreateThreadEx()` rather than simply calling `CreateRemoteThread()`?

3) This probably isn't the cause of your problem, but... You're failing to allocate memory for the null terminator in the string, you should be allocating `strlen(dllName) + 1`.

4) I assume that the process that is doing the injecting and the process that you're injecting into are both the same architecture, you're not running an x86 exe on x64 and expecting to inject into an x64 exe?

Comment: 1: I'm running a version of windows later than Vista, but how should I got about it then? I read that it was possible to inject code into protected processes with NTCreateThread (answering 3) Maybe it's not possible this way... But then again, how do I get my code running in a protected process. Do you have any suggestions? Also why isn't it working in windows xp?

Comment: I would suggest that you get it working, with CreateRemoteThread() on XP first. I assume it works reliably for 'normal' processes? What about the answer to 4 and does the code work any differently once you fix the bug detailed in 3?

Comment: I've looked it up inside a debugger and the allocation isn't a problem everything fits within a nice 0 initialized buffer. the dll is 32 bits and works normaly on both x64 & x86 systems but not on the system processes, I will however double check

Comment: @Unknown, so what is the current state? Have you checked suggestion #4, i.e. whether you tried to put x32 dll into x64 process (which is wrong)?

Comment: I know this is an old thread but did you find an answer to your post ?

Answer (score 2):

Since it's hard to find the right answer to this problem, I am posting even though the thread is old.
I was trying to inject into x64 service on Win7 x64 and kept running into same problems. My solution was:

1. Compile both the injector and injection dll as x64.
2. Instead of CreateRemoteThread & NtCreateThreadEx (both failing) use RtlCreateUserThread.

Answer (score -1):

You must specify the full path to the injected DLL, otherwise it will not be found.